# Facebook FQL checkin table

Tags: facebook-fql

Why any query I do on the checkin table me back empty array? I am using the test console (http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/rest/fql.query/). 
Even the example shown here (http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/checkin/) 
returns me an empty array.

Thank you very much, 
Stefano

Answer (score 1):

You need to get the **"user_checkins" permissions** to access that information.

Check this out: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/permissions/

Cheers ;)